# MySQL JDBC Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am writing a simple database with a query that inserts some data, modifies a entry, deletes it, then prints out the rest.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SpotifyDB {
    //JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/spotify";
    static final int portNumber = 3306;
    static final String serverName = "localhost";
    static final String dbName = "spotify";

    //Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Open a connection to the database
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //Insert data
        System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO artist(artist) " +
                "values('Muse')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO album(album, artist, genre, year)" +
                "values('Drones', 'Muse', 'Rock', 2015)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = "INSERT INTO album(album, artist, genre, year)" +
                "values('The 2nd Law', 'Muse', 'Rock', 2012)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = ("INSERT INTO songs(song, artist, album, tracknumber, duration)" +
                "values('Madness', 'Muse', 'The 2nd Law', 2, '4:41')");
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        sql = ("INSERT INTO songs(song, artist, album, tracknumber, duration)" +
                "values('Mercy', 'Muse', 'Drones', 4, '3:52')");
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Records inserted into the table!");

            //Update data
            String sql1 = "UPDATE songs " +
                    "SET track number = 1 WHERE song in ('Madness')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);

            //Delete data
            String sql2 = "DELETE FROM songs " +
                    "WHERE song = Madness";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

            //View records 
            String sql3 = "SELECT * FROM songs";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql3);

            while(rs.next()) {
                //Retrieve by column name
                String song  = rs.getString("song");
                String artist = rs.getString("artist");
                String album = rs.getString("album");
                String track = rs.getString("track number");
                String duration = rs.getString("duration");

                //Display the values
                System.out.print("Song: " + song);
                System.out.print(", Artist: " + artist);
                System.out.print(", Album: " + album);
                System.out.println(", Track: " + track);
                System.out.println(", Duration: " + duration);
            }

            //Close the connection, clean up running functions
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC driver
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            //finally used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se2) {
            }
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

My SQL Database table is quite simple as well;

```
CREATE TABLE spotify.`songs` (
  `song` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `artist` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `album` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `track number` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`song`),
  KEY `songalbum_idx` (`album`),
  KEY `songartist` (`artist`),
  CONSTRAINT `songalbum` FOREIGN KEY (`album`) REFERENCES `album` (`album`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `songartist` FOREIGN KEY (`artist`) REFERENCES `artist` (`artist`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

and the console is returning me this error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
I am having trouble seeing where the table columns are not matching up, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Column names *really shouldn't* have spaces, for exactly this reason.  But if your column names *must* have spaces then you need to qualify them with back-ticks exactly as you do in your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
INSERT INTO songs (song, artist, album, `track number`, duration) VALUES ...
```

Otherwise after the identifier `track` the query engine is expecting either a comma (to move on to another identifier) or a close parentheses (to end the list of column identifiers).  It finds neither of this, and immediately finds another identifier (`number`, which may even be a reserved word?).  This confuses the query parser.

Comment: I made it simpler and just made track number one word in MySQL and Java but the same error arises; it still states a MySQL syntax error. Do you see anything else that might potentially cause problems?

Comment: @YungFung: Probably the `4:41` and the `3:52`?  Should those be wrapped in quotes as strings?  They don't look like native data types.

Comment: So the syntax errors were solved- thank you for that! I also added auto incrementation in case but I'm getting a primary key error- com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Muse' for key 'PRIMARY', I am seeing from other posts that incrementation should fix this, I'll edit my post with the changes- any ideas?

Comment: @YungFung: According to your table definition, the primary key is a string representing the name of a song.  This makes the assumption that no two songs will ever have the same name.  This is *probably* an incorrect assumption.  That one column is responsible for too many things.  Create a separate identifying column (probably just an auto-increment integer) to use as the primary key and let the `song` column simply be the name of the song.

Comment: So it actually looks like the error is the repetition of adding the same primary key twice, which is the artist Muse. I tried allocating the primary key to a separate column artistid but since artist name is referenced as a foreign key it denies this. Are there any work around solutions?

Comment: @YungFung: Yes, the "workaround" is to use a unique value for the primary key.  An auto-incrementing integer would do the trick just fine here.  You'll of course need to update any foreign keys which reference the primary key so that they'd reference the new key.  Basically, never use non-unique values to uniquely identify something.

Comment: so mitigate the references to a number incremental system so that the string fields are repeatable. Thanks so much!